# How to install prawn plugin in rails 3.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

how to install prawn plugin.now i am using this command."rails plugin install https://github.com/prior/prawnto.git".its throwing following error in console.

```
Aptana Studio Workspace1/rails3/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Object::S (NameError)
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:10:in `require'
    from script/rails:10:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Think your problem may be "authored 3 years ago". 
I'd suggest using the gem http://rubygems.org/gems/prawn, which is much more up to date and well supported. Just put it in your gemfile

```
gem 'prawn'
```